# Shutdown rosout

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-groovy, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I have a ros application that has a GUI on top of it.  When I close the window from the GUI, I call `ros::shutdown()` in all of my nodes.  I checked to make sure I was killing all my nodes by using `rosnode list`. All my nodes are shutdown but rosout is still alive.  Is there a way to get rosout to shutdown without SIGINT? I would like my program to exit cleanly when the GUI window closes.

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66038/shutdown-rosout/) by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think rosout is kept alive by the roscore process. If you didn't want to send a SIGINT, you could try the answer on [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12751/kill-roscore-and-all-nodes-when-rosbag-play-finishes/) and add required="true" to one of your nodes that shuts down. That's if the core was launched with the launch file, of course.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on 2013-06-27**:
thanks, that works :D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosout is started and stopped by roscore. You do not need to shut it down manually. In fact, if you did shut it down, roscore would restart it.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1